# How to use "CONVERT" function in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, func

I tried:

```
from sqlalchemy import VARCHAR
result = session.query(Table).filter(func.convert(VARCHAR(8), Table.datetimefiedld, 8) >= some_date).all()
```

I got AttributeError: 'VARCHAR' object has no attribute 'self_group'

Can somebody please explain how to use the CONVERT function in sqlalchemy? Thanks!

Comment: try `func.convert(func.VARCHAR(8)...` or `literal_column('VARCHAR(8)')`.

Comment: @Paulo

It works for "func.convert(func.VARCHAR(8)..."!!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the canonical way to express this is:

```
func.convert(literal_column('VARCHAR(8)'), Table.datetimefiedld, 8)
```

Since an expression like `sqlalchemy.sql.func.ANYTHING(arg1, argN)` will be converted to `ANYTHING(arg1, argN)`, you can hack:

```
func.convert(func.VARCHAR(8), Table.datetimefiedld, 8)
```

What is the difference?

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import sql
>>> print sql.func.CONVERT(func.VARCHAR(8), Table.fied, 8)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(:VARCHAR_1), table.field, :CONVERT_1)

>>> print sql.func.CONVERT(
              sql.literal_column('VARCHAR(8)'), 
              Table.fied, 
              sql.literal_column('8')
          )
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), table.field, 8)
```

Both should work, but the second is more explicit (more verbose as well). If you are going to use it a lot, you can define:

```
def date2str(field):
    return sql.func.CONVERT(
               sql.literal_column('VARCHAR(8)'), 
               field, 
               sql.literal_column(8)
           )
```

An the use just:

```
date2str(Table.field)
```